# FPDF Error: Encoding not found: Tahoma.afm

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to convert tahoma.ttf file to tahoma.afm using FPDF's MakeFont() function as described in http://www.id.uzh.ch/cl/zinfo/fpdf/tutorial/tuto7.htm.

But Things go wrong and I get that error:

> Error: Encoding not found: Tahoma.afm

My code is

```
MakeFont('TAHOMA.TTF','Tahoma.afm','cp1254');
```

There is no upper/lower-case issue.

Then I have created tahoma.afm using command prompt

```
ttf2pt1 -a c:\windows\fonts\tahoma.ttf tahoma
```

Created a .afm file, copied it to my php file's location. I get still error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with the latest MakeFont function downloaded from FPDF.org and have finally figured out the problem. It was only a matter of examining the function and finding that you don't need to supply it with the location of the ".afm" file. The MakeFont function apparently only requires two parameters :

```
MakeFont($fontfile, $enc='cp1252', $embed=true)
```

The corresponding afm file needs to have the exact same name in order for it to work. So this is how you would generate the font :

```
MakeFont('tahoma.ttf', 'cp1252');
```

Answer (score 0):

filename first character need to be lower case

I success.